# Где указывается имя таблицы в модуле Album ZF2?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework-2

Пытаюсь создать свой модуль для ZF2 на основе примере из документации (Модуль Album).
Столкнулся с проблемой, что не выводятся записи из моей таблицы. Я не могу понять в каком конкретном месте указывается имя таблицы, с которой работаем.

Писатели документации не позаботились о новичках и назвали контроллер, модель и название своей таблицы "album", поэтому у меня возникают сомнения правильно ли я изменил названия под свой модуль.

Кто может подсказать номер строки, в которой нужно указывать имя моей таблицы https://github.com/Hounddog/Album/blob/master/src/Album/Model/AlbumTable.php

Answer (score 1):

В строке [`return new TableGateway('album', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);`](https://github.com/Hounddog/Album/blob/master/Module.php#L38)